# diagnosing networking issues in ubuntu

Tags: networking

I've been fighting for quite a while with my wifi connection. Basically, the problem is that it disconnects, but doesn't reconnects automatically. Instead, an applet prompts me to reconnect, this happens every 10'.

### My tries

I thought the problem would be Network Manager, so I connected using Networkd, but I couldn't just get it working just by starting the service, because the wifi card has to be configured somehow.

Network Manager uses **wpa_supplicant** in the backend, and I wonder if the problem would how NM is using wpa_supplicant, as they have different files for different drivers, for example:

```
$ ls /lib/systemd/system/wpa_\t
wpa_supplicant-nl80211@.service
wpa_supplicant.service
```

I've also checked out that the NetworkManager services configuration file has a restart on failure.

I am not sure what to do or try and some help to diagnose and troubleshoot this will be very welcome.

### Fix

The network managers seem not be easy to configure, at least they need:

1. an interface (wireless or lan), a network name and a password. We may need to wake up the interface, and may end up "unmanaged" until we manage it.
2. Plus -I believe- a supplicant like **wpa_supplicant**
3. and services files to handle crashes, start at boot etc

I don't know the internals but what you can do with NM which is to configure ( **1.** ) it using the **nm-applet** or **nmcli** (where we give the password for the network and select the network, for example). I don't see this client for networkd. For example **networkctl** just checks the connection. So it can't be done with networkd (there is no applet afaik).

The next way to config step **1.** is a bit lower level config and is using **netplan**. This is a great program because writing config files is probably difficult. I found it quite easy, this is the config I wrote (YAML format):

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
# no, let networkd do it cuz NM troubles this pc
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "Xg-wifi-Network":
          password: "rh6haeXX"
```

You can also add DNS servers, etc. [Here are neat examples.](https://netplan.io/examples/)
Then use this commands:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
sudo netplan generate && sudo netplan apply
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
systemctl start systemd-networkd.service
systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
```

And the output of the last command is:

```
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-02-16 19:36:08 GMT; 15ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-networkd.socket
...
Feb 16 19:36:08 code systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 16 19:36:08 code systemd-networkd[8000]: wlp1s0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 16 19:36:08 code systemd-networkd[8000]: Enumeration completed
Feb 16 19:36:08 code systemd-networkd[8000]: wlp1s0: Connected WiFi access point: OBT For Small Biz_JMTA (d6:35:1d:7e:76:6>
Feb 16 19:36:08 code systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
```

### Network Applets

Network manager comes with the neat **nm-applet**. I tried [this one from @pltanton, for Awesome Window Manager.](https://github.com/pltanton/net_widgets) It is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different service should solve the issue.

Try running `sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd` and `sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd`.

Note: You may have to disable NetworkManager by running `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager`.

Another thing to try is `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` or `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd` (if you do not want to use NetworkManager)

For more information, view [this](https://www.xmodulo.com/switch-from-networkmanager-to-systemd-networkd.html) page.

Comment: hi, it connects but same problem. Including logs

Comment: I added a little bit of information. I hope it is more helpful (suggested to restart network services)

Comment: with your help, and after some trials, Igot it working. Iwill update the post, and accept your answer. If yo think it is a good information, please include it in your post for other beginners

Comment: I can't believe it is not crashing, such a relief. I've added some details in the OP. Thanks to you.

Comment: You are very welcome.